# PHP variable in session variable

Tags: php, session, variables

I am trying to use a session variable like this:

```
$string = 'abc';    
$_SESSION[$string];
```

But I get access if i use it like this:

```
$_SESSION['abc'];
```

But I get always an error like this:

```
Notice: Undefined index: abc
```

Any ideas to solve my problem? :/

Comment: firstly You have to set some value to this session attribute.

Comment: Are you trying to create a session variable or are you expecting it to have been created already?

Comment: I expecting it to have been created already. I get the right value if I use $_SESSION['abc'] but $_SESSION[$string] doesn't work for me.

Comment: Make sure that `$_SESSION[$string] = "Some_Value"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply calling

```
$string = 'abc';    
$_SESSION[$string];
```

is not enough. It's only becomes available when you assign some value to it.

```
$string = 'abc';    
$_SESSION[$string] = 'test';

echo $_SESSION['abc']; //test
```

Also, make sure that `session_start()` is called on a page you're accessing it.

Comment: yeah echo $_SESSION['abc'] works fine but not echo $session[$string]

Comment: `$session` is not predefined superglobal variable. if you simply want to make it work, then assign a reference like `$session =&$_SESSION` above